# Shall I copy server's ca.crt to the client?

Tags: openvpn

I'm setting up an OpenVPN server and I need a little info: do I need to copy the server's ca.crt to the client?
I have tried both ways and only when I do that I can get it working; I would like to know whether what I've done is correct because otherwise do I need to build the certificate on the client-side (`./build.ca`) just for the client.crt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client has to accept the ca-chain of your server.

So if you are using a selv made certificate that is the way to go.

**Update:**
[Further reading about ca-chains and root-CAs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate)

Comment: May you give me some reference where I can read more about?

Comment: @black I found a good starting point and added the link to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Generate ca.crt on th **server side**.
And yes, you have to copy it by the client side.